# How can I mantain the position in a list group when I go back from a destination link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Developing an angularjs app with bootstrap, I have a web generated after a promise. Then, there is a long list group with linked items. This list is generated with ng-repeat.

When I click on an item and then go back, I lost the position where I was in the list and it send me to the top of the list.

How can I go back and restore the position where I was?

Here some code:

```
<div class="list-group">         
  <a id="{{pos.id}}" class="list-group-item" bindonce ng-repeat="pos in elements" ng-click="go('/otherPlace/{{pos.id}}')">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" bo-bind="pos.id"></h4>
    <span class="list-group-item-text" bo-bind="pos.description"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have the ID (pos.id) in every element of the list, but I don't know how to put the scroll in a specific id. 
If I build the URL with the traditional format (URL#id) nothing happens.

At the destination url there is a button for coming back. This is the code:

```
$scope.returnToMainPage(){
  $window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: can you give your code in a fiddle?

Comment: You can try adding an id to the clicked item before redirecting to the next page. and when you come back to the page, append that id to the URL. Just a thought.

Comment: @induprakash, I have an ID for each element. When I click an element, I store the ID, but if I add the ID to the URL, nothing happens. Thank you anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar problem solved in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29760881/4679838

Basically, if your web is generated after a promise or if your action (scroll) relies on the DOM, you have to execute your function after an angular digest cycle.

When you click at one element of the list, you have to store the scrollTop info. In order to do this, change the ng-click behaviour:

```
ng-click="saveScrollTopAndGoToURL ('/otherPlace/{{pos.id}}')"
```

That is the implementation of the function:

```
$scope.saveScrollTopAndGoToURL = function (destinationUrl)
{
    $rootScope.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    $location.path(destinationUrl);
}
```

Then, when you return from the destination URL, you have to restore it.

```
$scope.returnAndRestoreScrollTop = function() {
    $window.history.back();     
    $timeout(function() {
      document.body.scrollTop = $rootScope.scrollTop;
    }, 500, false); // There is a 500 ms delay before executing the function.
};
```